# Hypen before contribution amounts

Tags: civicontribute

I have been working with CiviCRM for years and I never had this problem before. I recently installed CiviCRM 5.56.0 on a new clients WordPress site, WP version 6.1.1.

I am attempting to set up a contribution page for donations the same way I always do, with the amount by itself without a label.  See screenshot below.
[image]

However, this is how it is appearing on the front end, with a hypen (minus sign) before the amount.  That should not be there and I can not figure out why it is there. Is it a bug in the latest release?  It looks like a minus or negative sign and can be confusing to donors.
[image]

This is how it looks in every other CiviCRM install I manage and how I need it to look in this install.  Can someone tell me what is going on and how I can fix it?
[image]

Comment: have you tried to replicate on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/? or try creating a new one

Comment: Yes I did.  I created a new contribution page and still had the problem   wpmasterdemo is so slow.  It just doesn't load.  but like I said. I have several other Civi installs that do not have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fix in 5.57 - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25033 - but I can't then explain why some of your sites don't have the problem. What versions are your other sites?

Comment: The other civi installs  are older versions than this one.  So I think you are confirming that this is an issue with 5.56 and upgrading to 5.57 fixes it.  I will do that today and see what happens.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you know when 5.57 will be released?

Comment: Jan 6, but if it's something that started in 5.56 we should try to get it into 5.56.1 which would be earlier.

Comment: Note 5.56.1 has been released with this fix today. @fdarn If you could click the checkmark under the up/down arrows beside the answer that would be great.

Comment: I just finished upgrading and the problem is resolved.  Thank you for your quick attention to the matter.